# How to do an anova with permutation in sas

Tags: algorithm, sas, permutation, anova, sas-iml

How could I do ANOVA with permutation in SAS? The purpose of that is kind of shorting the running time and save the output instead of print them out. I once used iml did a paired t-test with permutation. It went great. But I'm a bit concerned with if iml also can do permutation in ANOVA? 
I also tried multtest to generate permutations. multtest permute in a long way while iml goes wide way. Which would be more efficient?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you look at a recent paper that does an excellent job of describing how to implement a permutation test with SAS/IML. It includes code that is thouroughly annotated and efficient. See ["Permit Me to Permute: A Basic Introduction to Permutation Tests with SAS/IML"](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings15/2440-2015.pdf) by John Vickery.

Comment: thanks ricky~!!!!OMG!!it really goes into a lot of details. what if I have another within subject/ covariance, is it possible to do a correlated group ANOVA? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can implement whatever test you want.  For complicated tests, you might want to generate the permutations in SAS/IML, but then use PROC GLM for the analysis since it will be easier to specify complex models.